# Убрать окно подтверждения перехода без сохранения

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Сохраняю изменения в редакторе ajax'ом, поэтому когда обновляю страницу или перехожу с нее на другую, то вылазит сообщение "Подтвердите переход", а мне оно не нужно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его убрать?

Comment: Окошко "Подтвердите переход" означает, что была отправлена POST форма. Соответственно, ответ: избавиться от POST формы (с учетом того, что у вас редактирование на ajax'e, если все написано нормально, по идее, ничего сломаться не должно).

Comment: Да вот нет... Нет никакой формы вообще. Редактор расположен просто в ячейке таблицы, которая в <div>, который в другом блоке и т.д... Хотя пост форма есть, но редактор расположен не в ней.

Comment: Вообще у меня на странице есть помимо редактора который сохраняется ajax'ом есть еще и тот, который отправляется с формой. Теперь до меня дошло что это он выводит этот алерт... Но как его убрать...

Answer (score 1):

[[@Nikoole](/users/5731/nikoole)](/users/5731/nikoole) - то где расположена форма не имеет значения. Если она есть - то, при отправке данных и попытке обновить страницу(либо вернуться на нее обратно) будет предложено отправить данные повторно.

Вообщем, раз такие дела и вам столь принципиально - перепишите и форму на ajax, либо, на сервере, при обработке данных, делайте redirect (тогда окна не будет т.к. страница грузиться "с ноля", соответственно ни о какой форме браузер не знает, так делают многие, но это костыль)

Comment: Это не костыль, а обычная практика.  
Вариант 1: данные отправляются на страницу-обработчик, а она редиректит обратно на страницу с формой.  
Вариант 2: данные отправляются на ту же страницу, при обработке страница не выводится, а редиректится на себя же со случайным параметром для защиты от кэша.

Comment: Это обычная практика, да, но это костыль